# how would you import a variable from a library when you have a utility that references the variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I am using library XYZ that stores a variable in **init**.py.

I have the following files:

```
some_library/__init__.py
hello="frog"


file1.py
import some_library

def run():
  print(some_library.hello)


file2.py (at this point I can access hello from some_library/__init__.py).
import file1 as f1

print(f1.some_library.hello)
```

The import convention doing it this way seems a bit weird. File2.py is my main driver, and file1.py is a utility, while some_library is an external package that I need. Basically my utility uses some_library, and in my driver application I want to use the utility, but I need to check if hello from some_library contains some value.

In my driver application should I also `import some_library` and check `hello` or is it better to rely on the value of it from `file1.py` since I'm importing the full library there?

I need to be able to do something like

```
file2.py
from file1 import run, file1.some_library

if file1.some_library == "hello":
 run()
```

Comment: You can do what you need to be able to do if you just use `import file1` in `file2.py` and change `run` to `file1.run`.

Comment: Yes but then i have to reference everything by file1.xx. Is there a better method so i dont have to do that? @mkrieger1

Comment: Well since you wrote "I need to be able to do ... `file1.some_library`" I suggested that. Of course you can also use `from file1 import run, some_library` and then use the code you have shown except changing `file1.some_library` to `some_library`.